# passing ID parameter inside anchor href in Django template language

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-views, django-templates

My model name is keybase model and database is stored in mongo DB and object id can be accessed by '_id'. In views i have made object of that view

What i want is to make a delete button which goes in function of views along with object ID that is coming from mongodb

Here is the code of anchor

```
<a href="{% url 'Keybase_Management_System:Delete_Keybase' {{ i |mongoid:'_id'}} %}" role="button" aria-pressed="true" style="font-size:11px; display: inline;">
```

i the parameter value and mongoid: '_id' is custom tag that converts object _id to string id now this is showing parsing error that

> could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'

**What actually works**

If i use this `{{ i |mongoid:'_id'}}` separately it shows correct results for instance 9kas83n8d893n  but i want to move this id as parameter which i am not able to do.

`{{ i |mongoid:'_id'}}` works perfectly unless it is sent as as parameter inside anchor tag in href
I know there is some sort of syntax error there might be way to send this but i am not able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Remove the curly braces and try this below -

```
<a href="{% url 'Keybase_Management_System:Delete_Keybase' i|mongoid:'_id' %}" role="button" aria-pressed="true" style="font-size:11px; display: inline;">
```

You should not have curly braces inside `{% %}`.

Comment: in DTL it necessary

Comment: any error you are getting after removing the curly braces?

Comment: Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/kms/archive/url%20'Keybase_Management_System:Delete_Keybase'